# Centipede game of 2 students

Tags: game-theory, solution-verification

**PROBLEM**

We have two students who both begin with 1 point, their utility is equal to the number of points they have. Student $1$ has the first turn, he can decide to end the game and both students receive their current points, hence they have combined utility $(1,1)$. The student can also decide to pass on the game to student $2$ but he will lose 1 point while student $2$ receives $2$ extra points, student $2$ has now the same choices as student $1$, to end or to pass on the game. The game ends when both students have 60 points. What is the Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium in this game?

---

**MY APPROACH**

We derived the following utility formula for student $2$: when $n$ is even, $u_2 = n$, when $n$ is uneven, $u_2 = n + 2$. Hence, when $n = 58$, $u_2 = 58$ and student $1$ has to make a decision. If he decides passes the game on his utility will reduce by $1$ and $u_2 > 60$, and student $2$ will end the game, hence student $1$ will decide to end the game straightaway. Student $2$ knows this the turn beforehand and ends the game himself when he has $u_2 = 59$ in turn 57. Student $1$ knows this and will end in turn 56 and so on. By backtracking we find out that student $1$ will end the game in his first turn and the Subgame Perfect Nash Equilibrium would be that the student who has the turn in turn $i$ will end the game straightaway.

---

Can anybody please tell me if I did this correct?

Answer (score 1):

This seems correct to me. For further reading, I recommend you the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centipede_game#Equilibrium_analysis_and_backward_induction) article on Centipede game. 
Note, that they're a lot more Nash equilibria but your condition of being subgame perfect eliminates all non-credible threats from this.